# How to print an image in processing

Tags: image, file, pdf, processing

I am trying to print an image off the internet in processing.

I have tried looking at the processing website and found some code I thought should work:

```
import spaceInvadersEnemy.pdf.*;   

void setup(){
  size(800, 600);

}

void draw(){

  size(600, 600);
  beginRecord(PDF, "spaceInvadersEnemy.pdf");     // Start writing to PDF
  background(255);                  
  stroke(0, 20);                     
  strokeWeight(20);                 
  line(200, 0, 400, height);        // Draw line to screen and to PDF
  endRecord();
}
```

But I always got an error on the line with:

```
import spaceInvadersEnemy.pdf.*;
```

The error says "No library found for spaceInvadersEnemy.pdf"
I know that I need to include the file somewhere but I don't know where.

I am trying to just simply print an image of a space invaders enemy can someone please help me.

Comment: `import` statements should be at the top of your code.

Comment: Thanks that gets rid of my first error but now I have an error saying that it can't recognize the file. How do I include the file in the code

Comment: Your import statement is not correct. What exactly are you trying to import? Please read [this guide](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries) on libraries in Processing.

Comment: I am trying to import this image: http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/132/5/6/space_invaders_enemy_type_2_by_maleiva-d4x3vwl.png

Comment: I am trying to add just that image of an enemy in space invaders

Comment: Did you read the guide I linked? You only need to use import statements if you're trying to use a library. What library are you trying to use? If you don't need a library, then you don't need an import statement. Maybe check out the reference for image files?

Comment: I actually just figured it out. This page shows how to do it https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by going to the processing website and looking at the load image function it is right here: [LoadImage() syntax page](https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html)
If you have this problem you need to create a `PImage` then load it with the file name like this: `spaceInvadersEnemy = loadImage("spaceInvadersEnemy.png");` you render it by using the image function: `image(PImage, xPosition, yPosition, width, height);` The width and height are not needed though. Your code should look something like this:

```
void setup() {
    size(800, 600);
    spaceInvadersEnemy = loadImage("spaceInvadersEnemy.png");
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
    image(spaceInvadersEnemy, x, y, 50, 50);
}
```